# Separation of integral by approximation

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, approximation, approximation-theory, approximate-integration

I'm working with the following integral
$\displaystyle\int_0^y \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{1-ax-bx^2}}$ and would like to split it in something like
$$\int_0^y\frac{dx}{x \sqrt{1-ax}}+\int_0^y\frac{dx}{x \sqrt{1-bx^2}}$$ or something like that (separate the  integrals in one that only depends on $a$ and one that only depends on $b$, but I definitely want to keep the $a$ dependent one as I've written it!). Is that possible? I don't need anything exact, approximations work for me too!!!

Comment: This will be difficult to achieve as the position of the roots of the denominators, hence the positions of the vertical asymptotes will not coincide.

Comment: What about something like $\int \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-ax}+\frac{b}{2}x}$?

Comment: That doesn't address the issue of the asymptotes.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the indefinite integral $\int \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{1-ax-bx^2}}$ is $\ln(x)-\ln(2\sqrt{1-ax-bx^2}-ax+2)+C$.

With the bounds provided in the problem, the integral would not converge as $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \ln(x) =-\infty $

Comment: You could actually see this without doing it explicitly, because in a neighborhood of zero you have that the integrand is at least $1/(2x)$ (even allowing for $a,b<0$).

Comment: Actually, $\int_{0}^{y}\frac{dx}{x*\sqrt{1-ax}}$ is something like $arccosh(\frac{2}{ay}-1)$

Answer (score 0):

For $x$ close to $0$, we have $\sqrt{1-ax-bx^2}$ close to $1$ and therefore $<2$.  Consequently for $y>0$ we have
$$
\int_0^y \frac{dx}{x \sqrt{1-ax-bx^2}} \ge \int_0^y \frac {dx}{x\cdot 2} = +\infty.
$$

If you had $\displaystyle\int_1^y$ instead of $\displaystyle\int_0^y$ then it would be a harder problem: we'd have to find an antiderivative of the function begin integrated.